# Align multi pictures with their titles and descriptions

Tags: graphics, multicol, tabulary

I am using rmarkdown to produce this kind of report. I used framebox to show that pictures' sizes are not same. I am trying to align 11 pictures (6 pictures per row, 2 rows), with different sizes, add title on the top and paragraph under each picture. 
Title is mix between 1 and 2 lines. [Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NC1A0WsQukdrSM2qU0-fZ6wa3mesWpT2?usp=sharing)

[image]

```
\setmainfont{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\Ofont{Oswald}
\newfontfamily\ORfont{Oswald Regular}
\newfontfamily\RMfont{Roboto Medium}
\newfontfamily\RLfont{Roboto Light}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2cm}
 \begin{multicols}{6}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Agriculture}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Agriculture}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Transport}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Transport}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\columnbreak
\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Education}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Education}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont Water, Sanitation \&\\Urban Services}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Water, Sanitation & Urban Services}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\columnbreak
\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Energy}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Energy}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont Industry \&\\Mining}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Industry & Mining}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\columnbreak
\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Finance}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Finance}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Real Estate}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Real Estate}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\columnbreak
\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Health}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Health}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont  \\Others}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Others}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\columnbreak
\textbf{\ORfont{\fontsize{11}{48} \selectfont Information \&\\Communications}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}\framebox{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Information & Communications}}\\ 
\vspace{10mm}\columnbreak
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please consider adding a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to align all of your pictures is probably to put them in a table, for example using the `tabular` environment. I made a small example here, with blank pictures. To have the text centered both vertically and horizontally in each cell, I defined a new column type `C` based on the `m` column type from the `array` package. Also note that you probably do not need to use any `framebox` even if the pictures' sizes are different, since you can specify the size directly in the optional argument of `includegraphics`.
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newlength{\colwidth}
\setlength{\colwidth}{2.8cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{C{\colwidth}C{\colwidth}C{\colwidth}C{\colwidth}C{\colwidth}C{\colwidth}}
    Agriculture & Finance & Information \& communications & Title 4 & Title 5 & Title 6 \\
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{a} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{b} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{c} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{d} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{e} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{f} \\
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects \\
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m \\[4mm]
    Ttile 7 & Title 8 & Title 9 & Title 10 & Title 11 & Title 12 \\
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{g} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{h} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{i} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{j} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{k} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{l} \\
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects & 
        11 projects \\
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m & 
        \$US 11.0m \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```